# Can't use for loop to fill array in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, loops, calendar, fullcalendar

I need to fill a calendar fullcalendar using javascript, I have these code where data is what I receve from the database, but it send an error:

```
 var i;
 var events=[];
 var color_hour=[];
 for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   if(data[i]['hour_status_id']=="1" || data[i]['hour_status_id']=="2" || data[i]['hour_status_id']=="3"){ color_hour[i]="red"; } else if(data[i]['hour_status_id']=="0"){ color_hour[i]="blue"; }
 }
 events=[
   for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    { 
     id : data[i]['medical_agenda_id'], 
     start : data[i]['date']+'T'+data[i]['time_start'], 
     end : data[i]['date']+'T'+data[i]['time_end'], 
     color: color_hour[i],
    },
   }
 ]
```

It seems like the error is in the for cycle inside the array. Any clues hoy to fix it?

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: Syntax is invalid at: `events=[ for...`

Comment: This is unrelated to fullCalendar really, you just need to learn how to add things to arrays in Javascript. Syscall's answer will hopefully put you on the right track, and you can find lots of tutorials about it if you search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a `for` inside an array declaration. You could use [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add element inside it.

```
var i;
var events=[];
var color_hour=[];
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    if(data[i]['hour_status_id']=="1" || data[i]['hour_status_id']=="2" || data[i]['hour_status_id']=="3"){ 
        color_hour[i]="red"; 
    } 
    else if(data[i]['hour_status_id']=="0"){ 
        color_hour[i]="blue"; 
    }
    events.push({ 
        id : data[i]['medical_agenda_id'], 
        start : data[i]['date']+'T'+data[i]['time_start'], 
        end : data[i]['date']+'T'+data[i]['time_end'], 
        color: color_hour[i],
    });
}
```

Note that the two `for` doesn't seems to be required and could be done inside only one loop.